# Why doesn't my SSI work?

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2

I am having problems with passing query params into SSI include from within my zend framework application.

I am trying to include a PHP file inside another PHP:

```
<!--#include virtual='/ssi/test.php?x=hello' -->
```

This executes properly, if my hellotest.php (which contains the above line) resides in my document root.

If, however I do the same thing from within my  template.phtml (not /public_html/hellotest.php anymore) (I am using Zend Framework for this project) , the test.php is called and executed without any query parameters (in this case x=hello). No query parameters are passed into test.php from withitn my zend_framework templates .

Does this have anything to do with the way zend framework uses .htaccess ?
Here is a copy of my .htaccess files (in web root: /public_html/.htaccess)

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*/?)(.*css)$ combine.php?type=css&files=$1$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*/?)(.*js)$ combine.php?type=js&files=$1$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

EDIT: I've recently found out, that it will pass parameters into the SSI taken from URL . So if in my browser I type http://www.test.com/controller/action?param1=something , it will actually pass param1 into the SSI , but it will totally ignore the params I have on the SSI line. ... anyone has experience with this ?

EDIT2 - in response to Tim Fountain: correct, my test.php is at public_html/ssi/test.php .. However, I am calling from a ZF template file , which gets parsed by ZF always..not sure what you ment by "as long as it's not parsed by ZF" . In my test.php I simple output var_dump($_GET) - nothing else is in that php file, just that one line. And the way I call it from the ZF template file is like so: `<!--#include virtual='/ssi/test.php?x=hello' -->`

. the strange thing is, that if I type http://mydomain.com/controller/action/?x=hi_there , it will actually pass that X param to my SSI include line , and will overwrite whatever I had there originally (x=hello) . If I don't pass anything in the URL, nothing will get passed to SSI.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a PHP include? <?php $x = 'hello'; include 'test.php' ?>

Comment: yes, I need SSI becuase of caching mechanisms... include function wouldn't help me in this case.

Comment: Is your Apache configured to treat .phtml files as PHP scripts?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I created a test.php saying `<?php var_dump($_GET) ?>` and that printed just fine included both from inside and outside of Zend. I take it `Options +Includes` is already set in your server config and you don't need to add it to your `.htaccess`? Could it be caused by something inside your test.php?

Comment: My test.php is very simple:

<?php
echo "Num of args passed: ".count($_GET);
?>

I've tried absolutely everything :( Someone please help me!

Comment: Can you describe what that _everything_ is? Is Varnish enabled or not? Which versions of Apache, PHP and Zend Framework are you on? Can you create some sort of minimal test case? E.g. what happens if you replace the contents of Zend's `index.php` by `include('template.phtml')`? etc.

Comment: mercator: I tried your suggestion with include in the index.php and came to this : 

in my index.php :
include('/www/sites/2.somedomain.com/application/views/test.phtml');
$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('main');

if I comment out the line below -- bootstrap('main') , it will start working .So it seems like Zend Framework kills the parameters internally somehow ..because if i get rid of the zf's loop, (zend framework never gets started) it works fine.

My setup:
Zend Framework 1.10
PHP 5.2.4
Ubuntu 5.10
Apache 2.0

Thank you for taking time to help me !

Comment: Varnish is not currently installed on my box

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the info. What do you see if you do `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` in your `test.php` instead? Do you still see nothing? Are there any redirects or forwards happening inside ZF?

Comment: mercator: that var_dump prints out empty string . There are no redirects as far as I know (inside my ZF project, I am not redirecting anywhere)

Comment: Have you already tried `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php .phtml`? I'm afraid I've run out of ideas... Try testing on a fresh, clean ZF install if you haven't already, and then strip that down as much as possible till you find out what breaks it...

Comment: Yep, I've tried that. Currently I am investigating the source code of Zend Framework itself. It seems like everything works without problems with my layout templates are kept to relatively small size. Once I create 200+ identical links (with a href) ...the SSI breaks. It has absolutely no logic to it. The only thing I can think of right now is that Zend Framework somehow parses the output before spitting it out, and while doing so, it maybe runs out of memory or something. I have yet to find the part of Zend Framework which is responsible for this... :(

Comment: When I said "as long as it's not parsed by ZF" I meant the included file. I.e. if you view http://mydomain.com/ssi/test.php?x=hello in a browser does it work as you would expect? I still think it's much more likely to be a configuration problem on your server than a ZF issue - ZF doesn't do any special parsing of .phtml files, they are simply included using PHP's include command. If you were able to strip the code down to a minimal ZF application that still has the same problem as mercator suggested perhaps we might be able to spot something.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the SSI include, you could try using the php virtual function:

```
virtual ("/ssi/test.php?x=hello");
```

via http://www.zytrax.com/tech/php/php_ssi.htm

What kind of caching requires you to use SSI? Couldn't you just use something like Zend_Cache_Frontend_Output?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but that doenst' do anything .. I will keep looking into  this, meanwhile to answer your question:

My application will heavily use Varnish for caching, Varnish uses something they call ESI, similar to SSI . But I want to write my application in a way, so that if Varnish fails for whatever reason, the application will fallback from ESI to SSI automatically. That's why I need to make the SSI work somehow..but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen SSI used with PHP in this way so this is something of a long shot, but can you try changing:

```
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php
```

to:

```
AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/html
```

the reason it's not working is that your files no longer have a .php extension (or any extension), since you're routing everything through index.php. The change I've suggested will filter all text/html output (which should include PHP) though the SSI parser, instead of doing so by extension.

Comment: Hmm... That didn't work .. It didn't break anything, but it didn't help anything either...

Comment: I've tried this locally now and it does seem to work for me, as long as the PHP file I include is not parsed by ZF. I assume your test.php file is at public_html/ssi/test.php ? What method are you using to access the query params in test.php?